# how to find mean of columns in nested structure in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, data-structures

I've organized some data into a nested structure that includes several subjects, 4-5 trials per subject, then identifying data like height, joint torque over a gait cycle, etc. So, for example:

```
subject(2).trial(4).torque
```

gives a matrix of joint torques for the 4th trial of subject 2, where the torque matrix columns represent degrees of freedom (hip, knee, etc.) and the rows represent time increments from 0 through 100% of a stride.  What I want to do is take the mean of 5 trials for each degree of freedom and use that to represent the subject (for that degree of freedom).  When I try to do it like this for the 1st degree of freedom:

```
for i = 2:24
    numTrialsThisSubject = size(subject(i).trial, 2);
    subject(i).torque = mean(subject(i).trial(1:numTrialsThisSubject).torque(:,1), 2);
end
```

I get this error:

```
??? Scalar index required for this type of multi-level indexing.
```

I know I can use a nested for loop to loop through the trials, store them in a temp matrix, then take the mean of the temp columns, but I'd like to avoid creating another variable for the temp matrix if I can. Is this possible?

Comment: What happens if you give an index to `.torque`, i.e. `subject(i).torque(1)`?

Comment: try using `struct2cell` you should have more flexibility with multi-level indexing....

Comment: Nope unfortunately not darthbith - I get the same error if I use your suggestion, but thanks.  And Shai - I'm not familiar with struct2cell or why that would help. Can you elaborate?

Comment: @dustynrobots Is your question still relevant? Please consider marking the suggest answer as accepted, or revising it so that it can be answered properly.

Comment: @EitanT I answered my own question below based on a comment I made

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned above in my comment, adding another loop and temp variable turned out to be the simplest execution.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a combination of `deal()` and `cell2mat()`.

Try this (use the built-in debugger to run through the code to see how it works):

```
for subject_k = 2:24
    % create temporary cell array for holding the matrices:
    temp_torques = cell(length(subject(subject_k).trial), 1);

    % deal the matrices from all the trials (copy to temp_torques):
    [temp_torques{:}] = deal(subject(subject_k).trial.torque);

    % convert to a matrix and concatenate all matrices over rows:
    temp_torques = cell2mat(temp_torques);

    % calculate mean of degree of freedom number 1 for all trials:
    subject(subject_k).torque = mean(temp_torques(:,1));
end
```

Notice that I use `subject_k` for the subject counter variable. [Be careful with using `i` and `j` in MATLAB as names of variables, as they are already defined as 0 + 1.000i (complex number)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14790740/using-i-and-j-as-variables-in-matlab).

Comment: Thanks! But I'm not as comfortable with deal and cell2mat, so I ended up just doing it like this:   `for i = range
    numTrialsThisSubject = size(subject(i).trial, 2);
    for j = 1:numTrialsThisSubject
        subject(i).temp(:,j) = subject(i).trial(j).torque(:,1);
    end
    subject(i).torque = mean(subject(i).temp, 2);
end'

Comment: Okay :) your choice. I read your question as being how to achieve it without using an inner loop. There is no magic in my approach :) I suggest reading the docs and run the code line by line using the MATLAB debugger. This is the only sure to get comfortable.

Comment: Sorry I guess I should have phrased the question better - but thank you for rising to the challenge! I was trying to avoid a temp variable and another loop just because I thought the way I was trying would work but I had a syntax error I wasn't catching. But it seems like it just doesn't work that way, so adding another loop and temp variable was the next simplest execution.  Thanks though!

Comment: Did you try my approach? I am a bit interested in knowing if you got it working. Btw, the `deal` function is extremely useful if you want to extract data from structs. The syntax error is mainly because of MATLAB's limitations with data-structure lookup. You were trying to extract a single structure-element from multiple structs (the "trial(1:numTrialsThisSubject).torque(:,1)" part). This will be ambiguous to MATLAB and actually creates several returns. The deal-function is a way to get by this problem.